# TSQL XML check against records in table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a csv file that I am reading through and generating a XML string for it. I then send that XML string to the stored procedure and parse it out.

```
    SELECT      ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('transactionID[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('emailAddress[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('paymentStatus[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('shirtSize[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('paymentAmount[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('paymentDate[1]', 'DATETIME')
        FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/orders/order') AS ParamValues(x2)
```

From here, I need to loop over a table and see if the paymentStatus has been completed yet. If not, then we will update that row with the data we got from the XML value.

Whats the best way to accomplish that from this point?

Comment: #1, don't loop. #2 Post some sample DDL with some insert statements....and then say what you want to compare and update.  #3 don't loop  #4 don't loop

Comment: It is not quite clear, what logic you expect: select from existing table and join it with xml values for update or modify xml-based values according to 'paymentStatus' value? You should clarify your final target for the script

Answer (score 0):

Insteading of looping you should just be able to run an `UPDATE` statement with a join to the XML.

```sql
UPDATE target
SET [paymentStatus] = source.[data].value('paymentStatus[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM [Orders] target
INNER JOIN @xmlData.nodes('/orders/order') AS source ([data])
    ON --??  How do you match nodes in the XML to rows in the table?
    -- Maybe..
    source.[data].value('orderID[1]', 'INT') = target.[OrderId] -- ??
WHERE target.[paymentStatus] <> 'Completed'
```